# How to find webservice path in heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

So I have a web app with a specific route: http://localhost:28389/MyProjectName/webresources/test/ this returns just a json string:

[image: local]

But when I deploy my app on heroku the web app can't find the same path:
[image: heroku url]

This is my ApplicationConfig:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
      addRestResourceClasses(resources);
      return resources;
  }


  private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(pkgServices.TestService.class);
  }

}
```

And this is my TestService class:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestService {

 public TestService () {

 }

 @GET
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
 public Response getTestMsg() throws Exception {
     return Response.ok("welcome").build();
 }
}
```

Comment: Btw, on screenshots I see different URLs (with and without `/MyProjectName/`) - is it intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Read Heroku docs. They allocate port number for you and set it to environment variable. You have to use this environment variable in your application to bind http server to this port.

Note, you will still connect to your app at 80th port from browser.

Current problem is Heroku cannot forward request to your server because you do not listen on port which Heroku expects you to listen to.

Comment: I can't find the documentation where there is a example how to set the port in the application

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications

Comment: @AlexanderPavlor I did the exact same thing as this guy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118704/heroku-application-error-after-adding-heroku-http-port-to-procfile and I get the same error

Comment: Do you deploy `war` file? I was under impression you create fat `jar` and run it as Java app.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlor yes i deploy the war file: 'heroku war:deploy filename.war --app myherokapp'

Comment: In this case you do not need to care about port. How do you test locally - build war file and deploy to Tomcat?

Comment: yes locally it works but since heroku uses their own http port I added the procfile

Comment: you do not need procfile if you use their web-runner. Maybe, this procfile is a problem? " locally it works" - question is how it works. Do you build war and deploy to Tomcat or use IDE integration?

Comment: I use the IDE integration. I clean and build the project and then I run it. Should I try run it without the procfile

Comment: I suggest you try build and deploy war file as Heroku does. Probably, you will find it does not work even locally

Comment: according to the documenation: When using the heroku war:deploy and Heroku Maven Plugin tools, this option (setting http port) is configured for you. So theoretically there shouldnt be a problem during deployment

Comment: Exactly. It is why I think problem is with your `war`. You do not test it properly locally as you use IDE instead of building real war and deploying to Tomcat.